# Does the description of "making one's marque" in Kushiel's Dart make sense?

Tags: jacqueline-carey, kushiel

As I understand the system, the servant of Namaah's contract is sold for a certain amount: his or her marque. When she contracts out to clients, the contract fee goes to the house (or whoever owns her marque) and any patron gift (tip) on top of that goes the servant of Namaah herself. She then goes the marquist and pays him to tattoo part of her marque design. When the tattoo is finished, the artist has "made her marque" and is free to leave service or make her own deal with the house.

What seems odd about this is the flow of money. The money spent to buy the servant's marque ends up with the marquist. Is the marque tattoo designed to cost as much to apply as the price of the marque? Does the marquist kick back a proportion of the money to the servant's owner?

It's still not quite clear to me in *Kushiel's Chosen* (p. 91), when Phedre pays off Favrielle no Eglantine's marque with a large patron-gift.

> Four thousand for her marque, and four thousand against the House's loss of her art and labor in the time she would have made it.

Does the first four thousand go to her tattoo? Or to the house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to look up canon, but my impression from memory was that the payment to the marqueist was proportionate to the payment to the House. E.g. the amount of the tattoo you get is determined by how much of your marqee was paid off

Comment: That would make sense, but I'm curious: is it stated anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

The novels never make clear whether it is showing the entirety of the law with regards to indentured servitude contracts, and "making one's marque", but it does seem to imply that's all there is to it.  The contract holder earns against the services rendered while the contractee is under indenture, and the price of the marque simply goes to the marquist and acts as a very simple timer on the contract.

The value of the contract can vary; we know that simply from Phedre's example.  Her mother sold her for a certain sum to the Dowayne, the Dowayne sold her for a much higher sum to Delaunay.  None of that seemed to have any effect on the rules however.  In fact, the only mention anywhere that the cost of the tattoo come up is when Delaunay engages a master artist in the craft to do the deed, whose services are not cheap.  No mention of the marquist fee going back to Delaunay is ever mentioned, nor is it ever brought up when Phedre is in guild negotiations later on (which they ought to, as they are specifically discussing cases like Favrielle who cannot make their marque since they can't get patrons in the usual fashion).

Since there's no actual money link, this would lead me to believe the law was originally written so that the contract-holder was responsible for earning what income they may with the deal, regardless of how quickly the tattoo mark was gained.  Marquist's do seem to be a very specialized trade; it's possible their regular prices may be high enough to make that a definite bar to freedom.

Now, given the Night Court has operated this way for some time, and each of them has a standard marque design, I do speculate that they may have their own marquists they contract for each house, and there may be a smidge of price bumping or kickbacks involved, but nothing terribly systematic.  It's in their best interests to keep acolytes beholden to the House to gain income, but also to stay on good terms lest every acolyte jump ship as soon as their marque is done.  That'd be just as bad for business.

Addressing the last question directly: Favrielle's situation was mildly (but sadly, not completely) unique, in that her scars made her unfit to serve, and Eglantine was taking quite a bit of advantage of that, using up her genius for their other acolytes.  Random outside work like Phedre's was the only way she could earn anything at all for herself.  So yes, the first portion was entirely towards the marque, and the second... well, loss of services sounds a lot like a bribe to the house to me, since Eglantine had probably already gotten quite their worth out of Favrielle long since.